# Bootstrap js files per demo page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Per the bootstrap examples there is a block of js links at the bottom.  Where are these located?

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

When I downloaded bootstrap these were the only js files.

- js/bootstrap
- js/bootstrap.min.js

Do I have to download the rest individually?  The demo app itself when I download it locally isn't working specifically the drop down menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of these files are already included in the minified `bootstrap.min.js` you've got, don't worry about it. :)

Those files are what you get if you download the full Twitter Bootstrap source code, you can [view them separately at GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/js). But the standard download contains the complete Javascript and CSS files concatenated and minified, ready for use in production.

You may want to [check out the docs explanation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html).